# Condiciones: de saber vs. si supiera

Tags: condicional

¿Hay alguna diferencia en estas dos aseveraciones?

1. De saber, te diría. / De saberlo, te lo diría
2. Si supiera, te diría. / Si lo supiera, te lo diría

---

En inglés, esta forma se conoce como *inversion,* y su propósito es de mostrar énfasis en la construcción condicional:

1. Were I to know, I'd tell you. (En vez de decir *if I knew...*)
2. Had I known, I would've told you. (En vez de decir *if I had known....*)

Comment: Yo pienso que no hay ninguna diferencia, pero es una buena pregunta... me puso a pensar. Ambas tiene el mismo tiempo (presente) y la condición es la misma... mmm creo que son equivalentes.

Comment: Es interesante porque en inglés esto existe y y muestra que la primera forma es para énfasis.

Comment: Interesante... ¿podrías dar los ejemplos de ambas en inglés?. A mi solo se me ocurre una sola traducción para ambas.

Comment: @DGaleano cuando vuelva porque voy saliendo 

Comment: @DGaleano ahí las puse.

Comment: "Did I know, I'd tell you" no funciona.  "Had I known" sí.  También "If I had known."

Comment: @aparente001 vi la primera forma en varios libros. Quizás esté en desuso.

Comment: Creo que `Had I known` traduce `si hubiera sabido` o `de haber sabido` y eso cambia el tiempo.

Comment: @DGaleano claro. Puse dos ejemplos para que se vean las diferencias.

Comment: No entiendo porque la edición quitando **lo**. Con **lo** o sin **lo** es válida la pregunta. Si no estas de acuerdo con mi edición... no hay problema :-)

Comment: @DGaleano - Puse un comentario acerca de eso debajo de mi respuesta.  ¿Quieres explicar tu punto de vista al respecto?

Comment: Ustanak, quizás estás recordando mal lo que viste, o quizás el libro tenía un error.  Te digo con 100% de certeza.

Comment: @aparente001 sí. En realidad lo vi como *were I to know...*, pero esta forma se consideraba en desuso.

Comment: "Were I to know" se podría usar, en una frase elaborada con cuidado.  El significado es un poco diferente, pero sí se puede usar. // Yo de ti, quitaría "Did I know, I'd tell you" de la pregunta.

Comment: Ustanak, me gusta como editaste las frases. // "Were I to know" -- a mi aviso -- es otra cosa.  En cierta forma, tiene que ver con preveer el futuro.

Answer (score 6):

En el punto 26.5.4b del Manual de la Nueva Gramática de la Lengua Española (NGLE), encontramos esta descripción de la estructura formada por "de" + infinitivo:

> **26.5.4b.** La combinación "*de* + infinitivo" (en la que *de* se acerca más a una conjunción que a una preposición) suele tener valor condicional: *De no ser así quién sabe lo que hubiera pasado [...]; De haberlo sabido, estos años habrían sido más fáciles para mí [...]*

Mi búsqueda estaba en realidad orientada a confirmar por qué la oración (1) me sonaba mal, y creo que el motivo radica en la falta de un pronombre. Así como en el ejemplo de la NGLE encontramos "De haber**lo** sabido...", creo que -- para ser correcta -- la oración (1) debería decir:

- De saber**lo**, te lo diría.

Mi conclusión es que el verbo conjugado en (2) permite la omisión del objeto directo (OD) aunque "saber" es transitivo (en realidad, ese verbo parece compartir el OD con el verbo principal: te **lo** diría). En cambio, el infinitivo en (1) no permite el préstamo del OD del verbo principal, y requiere uno propio. Veamos otros ejemplos con verbos intransitivos y transitivos:

- Intransitivos: *De ir, iría solo* (en caso de ir, iría solo) / *De estudiar, estudiaría música* (si quisiera/decidiera estudiar, estudiaría música).
- Transitivos: *De necesitar**la**, pídela en la recepción* (si la necesitas, pídela en la recepción) / *De comer**lo**, hazlo con cuidado*.

En respuesta a la pregunta, ambas oraciones -- hecha la corrección indicada en (1) -- son equivalentes. No obstante, la estructura (2) parece mucho más versátil que la (1), ya que no cualquier condicional puede fácilmente convertirse en una frase preposicional con "de".

Comment: De acuerdo con tu respuesta, pero a mí la frase (2) me suena igual de rara que la (1) por el mismo motivo: la omisión del OD en la primera parte. Al igual que yo diría _de saberlo_, también diría _si lo supiera_.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo El pronombre siempre suena mejor si el OD es definido. Por ejemplo, esta oración donde el OD es indefinido ("algo"), su omisión no me suena mal: *De comer, comería algo caliente.* Ahora bien, cuando el OD es definido, clasificaría de este modo las oraciones de menos aceptable (1) a más aceptable (3): *(1) De saber, te lo diría -
 (2) De haber sabido, te lo hubiera dicho - (3) Si supiera, te lo diria / Si hubiera sabido, te lo habría dicho.* Para mí, las oraciones (3) funcionan bien, y por algún motivo (2) me suena un poco mejor que (1).

Comment: Excelente. En principio parecía una pregunta sencilla pero da lugar a respuestas como esta.  +1

Answer (score 0):

Voy a modificar un poquito tus dos frases:

1. De saber, te diría.
2. Si supiera, te diría.

Así me gustan más.  Quizás porque en tus frases, la primera parte de la oración no tiene objeto, y luego de pronto cae un objeto (pronombre) del cielo en la segunda parte.

Las frases son *equivalentes* aunque no idénticas.  Sin embargo, creo que son intercambiables.

---

Como había cierta incomodidad con por lo menos una de las frases, voy a construir un contexto.

> A: Leo, por favor, dime la verdad.  ¿Mi mamá ya sabe que soy yo el que rompió el vaso?
>   B: No sé, mano, de verdad.  De saber, te diría.

O bien:

> B: No sé, mano, de verdad.  Si supiera, te diría.

Comment: En verdad es así como deberían estar. Olvidé editarlo.

Comment: @Ustanak - Oye, ustanak, cuando puedas, ¿podrías contestar la pregunta de dgaleano, por favor?  También me interesa.

Comment: lo haré enseguida.